# error while using file operations in google appengine

Tags: php, google-app-engine

) i am creating a php application in google appengine. Since i will have to pay for the cloud sql, i decided to use some files instead of the sql database and read/write from it. but the problem is i am not able to create or modify the existing files using php's standard file operations like 'fopen' and 'fwrite',etc. when i run the same code in 'localhost:8080' it is working properly. but not in the uploaded version in internet. i am getting errors while creating/writing to the files. please help. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the appengine php runtime docs https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_The_sandbox

Specifically the section about the sandbox.  The crucial statement  -

> An App Engine application cannot:
>
> write to the filesystem. PHP applications can use Google Cloud Storage
>   for storing persistent files. Reading from the filesystem is allowed,
>   and all application files uploaded with the application are available.

Answer (score 1):

This was a while ago, but if you still want to write to file system,  you can write to the gs cloud

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/#writing_files_from_your_app

you need to add the bucket to your php.ini file

```
google_app_engine.allow_include_gs_buckets="yourapp.appspot.com"
```

and make sure your Service Account Name has permissions to edit the cloud storage

HTH

Comment: Is this free storage?

Comment: Google use to give you a limited amount of freestorage.  It was not available a week ago, but looks like it is available my latest projects by default.  I use for the writing cache data (app/storage) for laravel framework